# hide cell top border if the cells are empty

Tags: jquery, hide, border, cell

there is an OfficeInfo table with two rows which have two cells in each. the bottom second row's each cell has top border dotted which divides the top and bottom row in fancy way. I need to be able to hide the left border if the bottom left cell is empty or hide the right border if the bottom right cell is empty..that way if there is no content, there will not be just the border hanging in there for no reason..how do you do this using jquery??

```
<table class="OfficeInfo" border="0" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="15px">
  <tr>
    <td class="Office1" style="width=40%">  
     <span class="OfficeName">
     Munster Women&#39;s Center<br />
     </span>
     <span class="Address">
     8075 North Shadeland Avenue,  <br />Indianapolis, IN 46250         
     </span> 
     <span class="Phone">
     (321) 223-1232</span><br />
     <a class="mapdirectionsLink" href="#">map &#38; directions&#62;</a><br /><br />
     <span class="Hours">
     MTW: 9:00 AM- 5:00 PM</span>
    </td>

    <td class="Office2" style="width:40%">  
    </td>
  </tr>                                       
  <tr>                                    
    <td class="Office3" style="border-top:1px dotted silver;  width:40%;">   
    </td>
    <td class="Office4" style="border-top:1px dotted silver;  width:40%">                           
    </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery :empty selector to target the empty TD's and change the border CSS property. Assuming the top two cells are never empty you could do something like

```
 $('table.OfficeInfo td:empty').css('border', '0px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
  $('table.OfficeInfo tr:last > td').each(function(){ 
        if($.trim($(this).html()) == ""){
             $(this).css('border', '0px')
        }
  });
```

Hope this helps

Thanks.